# How to Improve Native Magento Search Functionality

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, search

I'm trying to establish what the best practices are for promoting relevant search results on a new installation of magento. On a code level, are there any recommendations for:

- core-overrides or
- event-observers

Which you'd recommend implementing to promote more relevance in search results? I've gone the route of setting search type to Like & Fulltext as well as minimizing the number of searchable attributes.

Unfortunately I'm still not very happy with the search results and definitely think that there is room for improvement.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: do you want to enhance current functionality? do you not plan to use a search server instead?. with that idea many options appear: sphinx, solr, elasticsearch.

Comment: Did you try Blast search Lucene extension?

Answer (score 3):

The key problem of native magento search is that search use "OR" logic. I.e. if you receive correct results for search phrase with one word, you will receive wrong result for search phrase with 2+ words.

You can change search logic in core file Fulltext.php (code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model) http://mirasvit.com/qa/magento-search.html

Or use ready solution (Mirasvit Sphinx Search Ultimate) with much better search logic/algorithm http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sphinx-search-ultimate.html

Comment: The problem isn't the `OR`s alone, it's that no weighting is performed to order multiple keyword matches above singles, or to prioritise some fields above others, like title over description.

Comment: Changing from "OR" to "AND" makes a huge improvement. Other than that, I have changed it to match beginnings of words rather than "anywhere". I.e. if you search "red", by default it would match "colored". With my modification, it matches "red" and "reddish". I also chop off the final "s" in search terms so that searching for "cars" gives you the same results as searching for "car."

Answer (score 2):

Other than code modification did you tried with  all the search related configurations?
The following links will provide the guidance to optimize the search with existing configurations settings.

http://www.linkbrightmedia.com/3-ways-drastically-improve-magento-search/

https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/5-tips-improving-on-site-search-results-using-magento-and-apache-solr/

http://www.betterstoresearch.com/blog/tag/improve-magento-search/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you need extended search as internal is <50% accurate, Sphinx/Lucene is 60-80% accurate and Solr (with fuzzy) is 98% accurate. Then you have cloud providers but those are enterprise levels costing high $100s per month. Most higher end sites use Solr (as we so) as it has the largest install base and highest accuracy.